# Mapbox LngLat object

Tags: javascript, mapbox

i have a little problem, need seperates two values from a LngLat Mapbox object. Im creating a marker on double click in the map. Works fine. The problem is that i need to store the value of longtitude and latitude in my database. And i have a problem with getting this values from lnglat object. I was looking in mapbox doc, but there is no any method for that object that could help. Is there any solution for this?

```
map.on('dblclick', (e) => {
const popupForm = document.querySelector('#marker-popup-form');
const popupText = popupForm['marker-infoo'].value;
// create the popup
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup().setText(popupText);
popupForm.reset();
// create DOM element for the marker
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.id = 'marker';
// create the marker
new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
    .setPopup(popup)
    .addTo(map);});
```

Comment: I can make and array of two values lng and lat like this ->
var el = e.lngLat.toArray();
The console looks like this then ->
[17.98925781250054, 50.48917145296127]
But i dont know how to get one value from this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution by making and array and then extract the value

```
// Here array.values() function is called. 
var iterator = el.values(); 
// All the elements of the array the array  
// is being printed. 
var myLng = iterator.next().value;
var myLat = iterator.next().value;
console.log('Lng = ' + myLng); 
console.log('Lat = ' + myLat); 
});
```

Console looks like this:

Lng = 18.263916015625682
Lat = 50.436719121999545